# Landsat8 collection 2 level 2 band ST_B10 - correction

Tags: landsat-8, land-surface-temperature

I am working on deriving Land Surface Temperature from Landsat8 collection 2 level 2 band ST_B10. Do I still need to correct for NDVI or is the temperatures accurate once the following corrections are calculated:

0.00341802 * DN + 149.0

I still seem to get fairly high temperatures (+10° Celsius than expected)

It would be convenient to bulk download only ST_B10 and QA_PIXEL and not full scenes.

Answer (score 1):

The temperature is in Kelvin. You can directly use the ST_B10 product from Landsat 8 as land surface temperature without any modification. But mind for these caveats https://www.usgs.gov/landsat-missions/landsat-collection-2-surface-temperature.

To bulk download ST_B10 and QA_PIXELS, check out NASA CMR API and download this dataset https://lpdaac.usgs.gov/products/hlsl30v002/